# How to safely navigate through nested maps with dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi i want to access a value if it is available at all points

```
token.metaData = newMetadata["721"][this.account.policyId][token.assetName];
```

I tried this, but it seems not to be correct syntax:

```
token.metaData = newMetadata["721"]?[this.account.policyId]?[token.assetName];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#syntax), you need to add the `.` after `?` for the bracket notation as well:

```
obj.val?.prop
obj.val?.[expr]
obj.arr?.[index]
obj.func?.(args)
```

So,

```
token.metaData = newMetadata["721"]?.[this.account.policyId]?.[token.assetName]
```

Otherwise, it will throw a syntax error because `?` will be interpreted as a ternary operator without the corresponding `:`

```
newMetadata["721"] ? [this.account.policyId] ? [token.assetName]
```

Comment: Thank you, i read the docs but didn't understand them

Comment: @wutzebaer In C#, it is `a?.b` and `a?[b]` without the `.`. So, it can be confusing